# Autowired annotation error in spring with java

Tags: java, spring

I have created a package com.springcore.autowire.Annotations which contains 4 files Emp.java, Address.java, awannconfig.xml, Test.java .

Emp.java contains class Emp with code as -

```
package com.springcore.autowire.Annotations;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;

public class Emp {

    private Address address;

    public Address getAddress() {
        return this.address;
    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("address")
    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public Emp(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{" + " address='" + getAddress() + "'" + "}";
    }

}
```

Address.java contains class Address with code-

```
package com.springcore.autowire.Annotations;

public class Address {
    private String street;
    private String city;

    public String getStreet() {
        return this.street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return this.city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public Address(String street, String city) {
        this.street = street;
        this.city = city;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{" + " street='" + getStreet() + "'" + ", city='" + getCity() + "'" + "}";
    }

}
```

awannconfig.xml file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- We get this template from documentation -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <bean class="com.springcore.autowire.Annotations.Emp" name="emp" />

    <bean class="com.springcore.autowire.Annotations.Address" name="address">
        <property name="street" value="PA-24" />
        <property name="city" value="Muradnagar" />
    </bean>
    <!-- more bean definitions go here -->
</beans>
```

Test.java contains Test class with main method to check use of @Autowired annotations .

```
package com.springcore.autowire.Annotations;

import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("com/springcore/autowire/Annotations/awannconfig.xml");

        Emp obj = (Emp) context.getBean("emp");
        System.out.println(obj);

    }
}
```

When I run Test.java file it is showing this exception -

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'emp' defined in class path resource [com/springcore/autowire/Annotations/awannconfig.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'address' defined in class path resource [com/springcore/autowire/Annotations/awannconfig.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.String' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency 
annotations: {}
```

Please help with this code as I cannot see any error.

Comment: Your `Emp` class only has a single args constructor. Either move the `@Autowired` to the constructor, or create a default no-args constructor in the `Emp` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The issue is coming due to parameterised constructor in the Address class whose constructor expects two parameters to be used to create a bean or object when you autowire it as there is no default constructor available.*

Solution of the issue.

Keep `Emp` class as it is :

```
public class Emp {

    private Address address;

    public Address getAddress() {
        return this.address;
    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("address")
    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public Emp(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{" + " address='" + getAddress() + "'" + "}";
    }

}
```

Keep `Address` class it is :

```
public class Address {
    private String street;
    private String city;

    public String getStreet() {
        return this.street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return this.city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public Address(String street, String city) {
        this.street = street;
        this.city = city;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{" + " street='" + getStreet() + "'" + ", city='" + getCity() + "'" + "}";
    }

}
```

Update **awannconfig.xml** to this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- We get this template from documentation -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <bean class="com.springcore.autowire.Annotations.Emp" name="emp" />

    <bean class="com.springcore.autowire.Annotations.Address" name="address">
         <constructor-arg value="PA-24" type="String"/>
         <constructor-arg value="Muradnagar" type="String"/>
    </bean>
    <!-- more bean definitions go here -->
</beans>
```

Output on my console.

```
{ address='{ street='PA-24', city='Muradnagar'}'}
```

**Remember :** Don't mix both **constructor** or **setter** injection as this will lead to confusion and unwanted errors.

Comment: @MayankKumarThakur This will work 100 %. Please upvote and accept this answer if it was helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much, Anish. Code is working fine now.

Answer (score -1):

Change bean configuration with constructor arg dependency injection, you missed that in emp bean definition. Change bean definition like below.

```
<bean class="com.springcore.autowire.Annotations.Emp" id="emp">
 <constructor-arg ref = "address"/>
</bean>

<bean class="com.springcore.autowire.Annotations.Address" id="address">
        <property name="street" value="PA-24" />
        <property name="city" value="Muradnagar" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Hi Amit, I did not miss bean configuration with constructor arg dependency injection. Actually, I am trying to do it with help of autowiring through annotations. Please suggest any solution.